# Custom Error from mysql to jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures, jdbc

I want to write a stored procedure in mysql that validates data before insertion into a table.
Then use JDBC to send back a custom message like "Zipcode not valid" back to Java so that it can be displayed on screen.
Is such a thing even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first I want to underline that @duffymo is **absolutely right**.

...But if you still want to write such a procedure this snippet might help:

```
delimiter ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_checked_zip(zipdata int)
BEGIN
    IF (zipdata > 0) THEN
        INSERT INTO mytable (zipcode) VALUES (zipdata);
    ELSEIF
        SELECT 'zip was invalid';
    END IF;
END
;;
delimiter ;
```

Note: it only checks if the passed zip is bigger than 0

Please think of doing these checks on the GUI level - they are less expensive and much faster (to list only 2 advantages).

Comment: Not sure I'd represent zip as an int.  The leading zero for states like CT is problematic, and it can't represent ZIP+4.  Better to use a varchar, IMO.

Comment: yes, you are right - but to be honest I really wanted to show how it _could_ work. The check of the zip is also only a stub and depends on the zip-format and so the datatype. The real implementation will definitely look different. That's the job of the OP, because she/he knows how the zip exactly looks like.

Comment: Thank you. I have decided to go for client side validation.
This answer definitely answered my problem.
TY

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of what MySQL and JDBC do, I think catching any exceptions and handling what is displayed to the user is the responsibility of the controller.

More importantly, it's a poor user experience to go all the way to the database to find out that you mistyped a zip code.  Validate it in the UI.  There should be no formatting issues with input.  I'd only expect to see that kind of message if there were business rules that were violated.

Comment: Thank you.
But I am having a problem. I insert values from many places (use cases) from the program. This makes me write the validation multiple times in different places.
This would have been solved if I write stored procedures for validation and simply call it during an insert.
Any suggestions please?
TIA

Comment: No, I still think that you need UI validation in each and every spot.  Are you saying that you're not doing any client side validation in your web UI?  That's a terrible design.

Comment: It felt simpler.

Anyway I have decided to implement client side checks.
TY

Answer (score 1):

I believe instead of writing sql procedure you should consider writing before trigger which would fire every time before insertion of row and can even stop row insertion if validation fails.